# VT-x not working, even tho it's enabled in bios and my CPU supports it

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I tried to make my android emulator work faster and as the title says, I can't get to install HAXM driver on my laptop. I've looked everywhere and did everything people suggested on other pages. Intel Virtualization Technology in bios is enabled. Updated Eclipse tools etc. Downloaded driver directly, instead of throguh Eclipse manager. I even tried to disable Hyper-V in Windows functions but it's not there.
I still get the following error when trying to install the driver:

(Can't post images so I will just rewrite it)
"This computer meets the requirements for HAXM, but Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) is not turned on. HAXM can be installed, but will not work until VT-x is enabled."

As I said before, it is ENABLED in bios so I have no idea what's the problem.
I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Some antivirus  prevent Haxm installation. In my case -- Avast : settings tab -> troubleshooting  ->   uncheck "enable hardware-assisted virtualization"  Solved the problem

A step-by-step tutorial can be found [here](http://www.itjungles.com/avast-antivirus-causes-error-haxm-cannot-be-installed-until-vt-x-is-enabled.html)

Comment: I had the same problem with Windows Defender. I enabled Device Security - Core Isolation. Disabling that resolved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

Although this is an old question, but I've still encounter it recently.

This is what worked for me on my i7-3770 3.40GHz, Z77 extreme motherboard running Windows 10.

In Windows, disable Hyper-V:

1. Open up a PowerShell or CMD session as Administrator.
2. Type the following command:
   dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V-All
3. Windows will ask you to restart.

In the bios:

1. Disable >>> Intel Virtualization Technology, vt-d
2. Save the bios settings and allow it to restart and boot into Windows.
3. Shutdown the computer (I've tried just restarting and it didn't work)
4. Power up the computer, go into the bios and re-enable the above disabled settings.
5. Save, restart.

Download the [Intel Utility](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/7838/Intel-Processor-Identification-Utility-Windows-Version) to check.

You should now see it been supported:

[image: Screen shot]

If it still doesn't work, try re-enabling Hyper-V first then following the steps above.

Comment: +1 for `Shutdown the computer (I've tried just restarting and it didn't work) `. I had to do a cold boot after re-enabling virtualization too before the changes were registered by windows.

Answer (score 2):

Hope my answer helps someone who ends up on this page for the question

I had just updated my BIOS and found that emulator on Android Studio was not starting mentioning "VT-x not enabled". When I checked task manager it showed Virtualization is Disabled

On entering BIOS found that Virtualization showed enabled. I exited and googled up in vain.

**How I got rid of it:**
I entered BIOS setup once again, this time I disabled it and re enabled. Saved and exited.
When I again checked in Task Manager, "Virtualization showed as enabled"

I made sure emulator is also running as I am typing this answer

Answer (score 2):

had the same problem with my elitebook-i7 while running windows 10 pro. just like @Sajkor non of the method worked that's why am advising you try this method out:

1. Search program and features and open
2. open "turn windows features on or off"
3. under hyper-v, expand hyper-v platform an disable Hyper-v hypervisor
4. Also disable virtual machine platform
5. save and restart the pc

hope it helps, see the image if you are lost

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICbEF.png

Answer (score 1):

do you have any other software installed on your PC, that may prevent HAXM to use VT-x ?
Maybe you've got some other SDKs/emulators installed that would come with a virtualization service ?

Also, what's your laptop ? Sometime BIOS may be buggy and to really enable VT-x, you may need to disable it, shutdown and boot your PC again, enable VT-x, shutdown and boot again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think I have any software preventing HAXM, at least none that I am aware of. The only thing I'm using related to virtualization is eclipse built in emulator (the one I want HAXM for). My laptop is ASUS R500V with i5 - 3210M.

Comment: Disable, shutdown, boot, enable, shutdown, boot did not work. Still the same problem.

Comment: Some time this happens because  of OS issue may be something missing i just formated my laptop  with another images copy and my emulator works fine.