# even though virtual technology is enabled in bios its not working

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

While working on the Android Studio as we set up the virtual devices it's showing to enable VT-x in the bios but when the VT-x is enabled and save and exited from the bios when working again a message is popped up saying VT-x is disabled .it would be really helpful if someone suggests me what to do in this scenario . Thank you

Comment: Is the machine running on Intel or AMD processor?

Comment: running on intel

Comment: have a look at this post, might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345389/vt-x-not-working-even-tho-its-enabled-in-bios-and-my-cpu-supports-it